# How to remove/change date format from a column SQL

Tags: sql

I am a below beginner when it comes to SQL. I am using SQL JOIN to join two tables and dump that data into a output file.

One of the tables(EMPLOYEE) has a column(BIRTHDAY) and on the output file it prints YY-MM-DD-MM-SS-MM format.

I only want to see YY_MM_DD format in my output file. I do not want to change the data or anything in SQL data base, as I am just reading it.

Here is my SQL command I run on cmd line:

```
sqlcmd -Q "Use GlobalStore select * from  EMPLOYEE Inner JOIN ADDRESS ON Address.ADDR_ID = Employee.EMP_ID " -s ";" -o D:\output.txt
```

Please note that I need to do this on Win7 cmd line. Can someone please help me?

Comment: First thing you could do is install SQL Server Management Studio Express, which will let you connect to your SQL Server database and test out your queries. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver2014express.aspx   Following that, go through a few tutorials on the T-SQL date and time functions, which should show you what you need to do.

Comment: What made you think I was doing this without having SQL Server Management Studio installed or I haven't done research? Its not like I pulled the command out of thin air, I did do the research and came up with the command, but it is lacking few things.

Comment: `sqlcmd` is a command line tool. SSMS is a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using wildcard selection in your command text like `select * from  EMPLOYEE`, you have to specify explicitly column names to select, and convert `BIRTHDAY` column value to string something like

```
select
    replace(convert(nvarchar(10), BIRTHDAY, 2), '.', '_') as BIRTHDAY,
    .... the rest of columns
from  EMPLOYEE
.... the rest of your query
```

Here `convert(nvarchar(10), BIRTHDAY, 2)` actually converts datetime value to the string using format `yy.mm.dd` and then `replace` function replaces dots to underscores to achieve your desired `YY_MM_DD` format.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. This is doing almost what I wanted. The only issue I have is, BIRTHDAY is actually in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:MS" format. Sometime I want to keep the date and time. But sometimes I just want the date, not the time. If I want just the date, how do I get the date, without changing "-" to "_"?

Comment: @usustarr not quite sure if I understood your comment correctly. Anyway, I've mentioned replacement "." to "_" only to fit "YY_MM_DD" format in your question. If it isn't needed - just omit replacement and use any appropriate format with [convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.120).aspx) function.